# Flutter OTA Update package

Tags: flutter, ota

I am trying to implement ota updates in a flutter app. I am using this package [Ota Update](https://pub.dev/packages/ota_update) to implement the ota update. For now I am following the example shown by the package documentation. How can I impement it in such a way that it checks the version of the app installed on the phone and compares it with whats stored in the server then proceed to download if a newer version is found.

Here is my code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late OtaEvent currentEvent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tryOtaUpdate();
  }

  Future<void> tryOtaUpdate() async {
    try {
      //LINK CONTAINS APK OF FLUTTER HELLO WORLD FROM FLUTTER SDK EXAMPLES
      OtaUpdate()
          .execute(
        'https://internal1.4q.sk/flutter_hello_world.apk',
        destinationFilename: 'flutter_hello_world.apk',
        //FOR NOW ANDROID ONLY - ABILITY TO VALIDATE CHECKSUM OF FILE:
        sha256checksum:
            'd6da28451a1e15cf7a75f2c3f151befad3b80ad0bb232ab15c20897e54f21478',
      )
          .listen(
        (OtaEvent event) {
          setState(() => currentEvent = event);
        },
      );
      // ignore: avoid_catches_without_on_clauses
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to make OTA update. Details: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('OTA status: ${currentEvent.status} : ${currentEvent.value} \n'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Remote Config will do and Package Info Plus.

Comment: This seems good for A/B testing, but this won't take care of a buggy code. Ex: The part that chooses Remote-Config key is wrong, how do we hot-update that? I have listed the known solutions and problems here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73855934/flutter-ota-hot-update-on-android-with-request-install-packages-banned