# Flutter OTA (hot update) on Android with REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES banned

Tags: flutter, ota, google-play-developer-api, over-the-air

I want a mechanism to push small-features and bug-fixes quickly, because Playstore-reviews are getting stuck for at least one week again. I checked [ota_update](https://pub.dev/packages/ota_update) which seemed promising, but it uses REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, which has been banned by Playstore for any new update / App. Next suggestion was to use [Firebase-Remote-Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286591/flutter-ota-update-package) but that does not help in a buggy-code scenario, it's more for A/B testing. I have not tried [Hydro-SDK](https://hydro-sdk.io/blog/fluttering-over-the-air/) because it involves using TypeScript. Another option is [Chimera](https://github.com/ChimeraFlutter/Chimera-Flutter-Code-Push) but from its Github activity, it seems very new and might not be stable. Requesting some suggestions on what steps I can take. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to [flutter_eval](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_eval)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will keep this in mind, but will keep it as a later option because it seems it doesn't have support for all Widget types yet. Also from their docs "Although flutter_eval is already the best solution for native Dart Flutter code push, it's still very early for the project and you should not expect existing Flutter/Dart code to work without modification." For a large and growing code-base, maintaining parity can also become difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own backend and define a route that checks if there is an update.

To do this, you store the latest version number in the database. Every time you want to run an update, you send the current version number of your app and compare it with the version in the database. If the version is smaller than the version in the database, then you can download your apk from a file server and run it.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. ".. download your apk from a file server ..." I think I will have to use otp_update pub package or some other similar way to do this. But Android will not accept new App updates with android-permission  "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES", which is needed for otp_update. So, how do I install the apk?